# Diagonal accordion dividers and skewed text flow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Fiddle (you may have to resize results pane): http://jsfiddle.net/BxVrf/1/

Objective: [image: Objective]

Problem:

0) As you can see, I am much better at graphic design than I am at code.

1) I am trying to have the accordion tabs diagonal (currently I can get it to work cleanly with vertical divs obviously), but short of creating a huge image I can't find a resolution-independent way of doing this. Using gradients will not work as I am using box-shadow, and a transparent border will show. CSS transforms also give less than optimal results, with or without zAccordion (I have commented them out in the Fiddle).

2) I would like CSS text flows as in the bottom image. I've found CSS Text Wrapper which is less than ideal, and a Fiddle posted elsewhere on here as follows, which again, returns less than ideal results and is currently not in the Fiddle pending first problem being solved:

```
var element, width, height, fontSize, numberOfParagraphs, lineHeight, numberOfLines, offsetIncrement, highestValue;
element = jQuery('p.all');
width = element.width();
height = element.height();
fontSize = element.css('font-size');
numberOfParagraphs = element.length;
lineHeight = Math.floor(parseInt(fontSize.replace('px','')) * 1.5);
numberOfLines = height/lineHeight*numberOfParagraphs;
offsetIncrement = 8.5;
highestValue = Math.floor(numberOfLines*offsetIncrement);

for(var index = 0; index <= numberOfLines; index++) {
    element.eq(0).before('<span class="text-offset" style="width: '+highestValue+'px; float: left; height: '+lineHeight+'px; clear: both;"/>');
    highestValue = highestValue-offsetIncrement;
}
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: :) well, at least you can agree now that graphic design !== web design

Comment: Thank you -- I have been away from web design for years and missed the jQuery/CSS3/HTML5 boat, but I'm catching up…

Comment: not quite sure, but I would kindly discourage you from going that direction. Tell your client that you did a terrible mistake and redraw your web concept ;)

Comment: Why? Not that I mind (given the right reasons), but I'm guessing it's not possible without ridiculous amounts of workarounds? I'd like to work it out if possible -- would help me learn as well.

Comment: just for example, what if one day you decide to throw somewhere inside the content areas some images? the whole concept might end pretty messy in my opinion

Comment: The website is primarily text-driven -- one of the few good things about "creative freedom". That, and it's being built for a one-off event, so updates will be kept to a minimum -- if at all.

Comment: The only way i can think of is to have each line a <div> and to slightly offset it to the one above.  That will give you the effect BUT you will have massive amounts of div's with the potential of making the animation sluggish or jagged.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BxVrf/6/ skewing the elements, but than you'll get a slightly 'italic' types of fonts.

Comment: Griegs -- the code snippet above does exactly that. The original Fiddle I got it from is here: http://jsfiddle.net/m4jLt/1/ (I have lost the SO thread, unfortunately)

Comment: Oh ok.  Nice effect but i think you are really creating a rod for your back.  is flash out of the question?

Comment: roXon -- Thank you, but it has the unintended effect of the skew cutting off at the <ul> edge: http://cl.ly/image/3A1s3e3Q1O1y

Comment: I know. I really don't know about Flash but this days I would kindly avoid doing such intense text types calculations just to achieve a diagonal text alignment.

Comment: RE Flash -- me neither! What about just the diagonal edges, without the offset text?

Comment: You would have to wrap the text in another element (`p` maybe) and apply a negative value to unskew to it. Unfortunately, the margins will also be unskewed, so the measure will look like square blocks again instead of that rhombus shape you want. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BxVrf/8/)

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for Skew not Rotate,

```
transform: skewX(20deg) skewY(0deg); /* W3C */
-webkit-transform: skewX(350deg) skewY(0deg); /* Safari & Chrome */
-moz-transform: skewX(350deg) skewY(0deg); /* Firefox */
-ms-transform: skewX(350deg) skewY(0deg); /* Internet Explorer */
-o-transform: skewX(350deg) skewY(0deg); /* Opera */
```

Here is your updated Fiddle with solution

http://jsfiddle.net/BxVrf/9/

Comment: Thanks! Some things though: updated with `transform-origin` property, the offset text snippet above, and a corresponding skew offset for the text, but still has kinks to be worked out -- most importantly, how do I get the right-most accordion to show up? Ideas welcome! http://jsfiddle.net/BxVrf/27/

Comment: Agree with @jBarks thatnx for improvement ^^

Comment: Additionally last accordion panel is cut off when active (this is probably a simple fix but escapes me right now at 6am): http://cl.ly/image/021g2p3r040P

Comment: Happy to see that it worked, don't forget to add, text- align: justify in #one, #two #three.... it will make paragraph formatting proper.

Comment: Well, you answer just reflects what we already argued in our comments on the question above... Or I'm wrong?